# How to use like ('s%') statement in a Dataset using asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql

How would I should add a parameter to the following query, using asp.net dataset.

```
SELECT word from wordTable where word like 's%';
```

The aim is to search for words starting with S.

Cheers

**Edit:
Answer is:**

```
SELECT word from wordTable where word like '' + @letter+ '%';
```

Comment: Why do you need `LIKE '' + @Letter + '%'`. Surely `LIKE @Letter + '%'` will suffice?

Comment: @GarethD this worked for me `LIKE @Letter + '%'`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
sql = string.Format("SELECT word FROM wordTable WHERE word LIKE '{{0}}%';", paramValue)
```

But this way you have to protect paramValue against SQL Injection!

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx

So I think best is (if not use SP's): Step 3. Use Parameters with Dynamic SQL

Answer (score 0):

```
string connectionString = "your Connection String";
string letter = "T";
DataTable table = new DataTable();
using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Word FROM WordTable WHERE Word LIKE @Letter + '%'", connectionString))
{
    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Letter", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1).Value = letter;
    adapter.Fill(table);
}
```